# MySQL union is not deterministic

Tags: mysql, union

Here is two equals query at first sight:

```
SELECT obj_id 
FROM obj t JOIN joined_a a  ON t.`id` = a.`obj_id`
UNION 
SELECT obj_id
FROM obj t JOIN joined_b b  ON t.`id` = b.`obj_id`;
```

and

```
SELECT obj_id
FROM obj t JOIN joined_b b  ON t.`id` = b.`obj_id`
UNION
SELECT obj_id 
FROM obj t JOIN joined_a a  ON t.`id` = a.`obj_id`;
```

They are different only with select's sequence.

result rows quantity from these two queries are different!

How does it possible?

If I add DISTINCT to each SELECT ... rows quantity will have NEW value, the biggest value!

If I add brackets to each SELECT like

```
(select ...)
UNION 
(select ...)
```

rows quantity will have the  DISTINCT's value.

Comment: could you please post your queries exactly as they are and some sample data (enough to reproduce)?

Comment: I think it is deterministic -- at least if `obj_id` has exactly the same type in both tables, so something is wrong with your test.  Conceivably, the types could depend on the ordering of the statements, but MySQL documentation claims that all subqueries are used to determine the output types.  You do realize that there is no guarantee on the ordering of the results, unless you use `order by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two queries will return the same rows, but not necessarily in the same order.

UNION dedupes the results for you, so the DISTINCTs do nothing and the size of the result set is the same regardless of the SELECT order.

The only explanation that fits your test is that some more data was inserted in between the running of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You are right!

I got into an insidious trap with  SQLYog ultimate GUI interface v11.11 BUG-feacher!!!

GUI adds to each query LIMIT 0, 1000; suffix 
:(

check queries at command line and it's work fine.

Comment: Yep, that'd do it.. guess there was another explanation after all!